# find value of $x$ in a way that the matrix has square root with real entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I want to find all possible real values of $x$ in a way that $X=\begin{pmatrix}x & -x & -1 & 0 \\x & -x  & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & x & -x\\ 0 & 1 & x & -x
\end{pmatrix}$
is the perfect square of a matrix with real entries.

Here is my try: I wanted to find square root of $X$. When $X$ is diagonalizable the question is much easier. But the given matrix is not diagonalizable. So I was looking for another way to find the square root of $X$. I guess it's related to Jordan form. But finding a basis for that seems so complicated for me. Also I guess it should work for all values of $x$ as the characteristic polynomial of $X$ does not depend on $x$'s value.

Comment: What is the background of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\;\;\text{and}\;\;
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
A^2=0,\;\;
AB+BA = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & -4
\end{pmatrix}
,\;\;
B^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore
$$
(aA+bB)^2 = a^2A^2+ab(AB+BA)+b^2B^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4ab & -4ab & -2b^2 & 0 \\
4ab & -4ab & 0 & -2b^2 \\
2b^2 & 0 & 4ab & -4ab \\
0 & 2b^2 & 4ab & -4ab
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So we just have to set
$$ a = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{2}} \;\; \text{and}\;\; b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and then $(aA+bB)^2=X.$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$
(t^3-t^2+5t+3)^2 \\
=t^6-2t^5+11t^4-4t^3+19t^2+30t+9 \\
=(t^2+1)^2(t^2-2t+9)+32t
$$
As $(X^2+1)^2=0$, we have $(X^3-X^2+5X+3I)^2 = 32X$ or
$$
\left(
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} (X^3-X^2+5X+3I) \right)^2 = X
$$